# Best way to manage a header navigation menu from within a template?

Tags: html, templates, grails, view

I'm looking to put navigation in my GSP template, and I would like to set the `active` class on the navigation elements for each respective page. What's the best way to do this? I have several `.gsp` views merging with a single template that looks like this:

```
  <div id="bd" role="main">
    <div role="navigation" class="yui-g">
      <ul id="nav"><a href="index.gsp"><li class="active">Home</li></a><a href = "products.gsp"><li>Products</li></a><a href = "contacts.gsp"><li>Contact</li></a></ul>
    </div>
    <g:layoutBody/>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like armandino's suggestion, however you may have problems if you're accessing pages by other means than clicking the menus (eg through a bookmark or the first page after login).

This is another solution if you're using SiteMesh, however it is not isolated to the menu template and hence not as nice design-wise:

[Grails active page navigation menu](http://www.aaideas.com/2010/03/26/grails-active-page-navigation-menu/)

Comment: This is probably the simplest and quickest way to implement this. It doesn't scale well, but that's not an issue in my case.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of passing a param, you can use some which are natively present:

```
<g:set var="pageId" value="${params.controller}-${params.action}"/>
```

Then on the nav items

```
<g:if test="${pageId == 'book-list'}"> class="active"</g:if>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is usually done by passing a param, let's call it `activeView`. Then in your menu template you can check which menu item to highlight based on the param's value:

```
<g:if test="${activeView == 'products'}">
   <li class="menuItem active">Products</li><!-- not clickable if active -->
</g:if>
<g:else>
   <li class="menuItem"><a href="products.gsp?activeView=products">Products</a></li>
</g:else>
```

I would also suggest having [controllers as the point of entry](http://www.grails.org/Tag+-+link), and not GSPs.

```
  <g:link controller="products" action="list" class="menuItem" params="[activeView:'products']">Book List</g:link>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another idea is to use the the [Grails navigation plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/navigation).

Answer (score 0):

I think a sitemesh pageProperty is an elegant in uninvasive solution that keeps things completely in view land.

in the particular page:

```
<body active="home">
```

in the sitemesh layout template:

```
<g:if test="${pageProperty(name: 'body.active') == 'home'}">
    <li class="active"><g:link uri="/">Home</g:link></li>
</g:if>
<g:else>
    <li><g:link uri="/">Home</g:link></li>
</g:else>
```